# Web application into web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment

I have the following requirement and I couldn't figure out a way to achieve it.

I have a mobile friendly web application developed using ASP.NET MVC. It works fine as a normal web application. Now my client wants it to be more like a native application (like the Facebook app for mobile, where you can download and install it and still opens in a browser window when you run the executable file.More importantly, all the fixes and updates are reflected in the application without having to re-install it.)

Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into Phonegap, Xamarin, or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said he wants to run application like website in browser. it sounds like that he just wants some sort of Shortcut for website.
Then you just create an application and fire your event to run site URL in browser.
as you said

> all the fixes and updates are reflected in the application without
>   having to re-install it.

means this is just a site.
in other case use Phone gap (http://phonegap.com/) it matches your requirements and uses HTML for styling and almost all features of an typical site.

**PhoneGap Support** to Different Mobile Plateform (Claimed by PhoneGap)

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_support_index.md.html#Platform%20Support

Answer (score 0):

The Native application need to be developed in separate platforms. Like `Android, IOS, Nokia, BlackBerry, Windows Phone` etc., If the Application requires all the platform apps.

In our concern we have developed few apps same as your requirement. When user wants to view in PC they can view entire web with responsive design. Same will work, if customer access from mobile with in mobile view. Entire application will work accordingly for `PC, TAB and MOBILE` with responsive design.

If you go for Native then the platform apps need to be developed and inside app they will use to call your `site url` with in `WebView`. Like PC Browser calls URL.

So, when ever you made any changes the changes will be reflected in your app also. without reinstalling the app. Since `webview` is calling only your URL. For this internet is must.

`You can make these kind of Apps with setups and designs through Online itself`. Just give your URL with that.

**Link Here :** [Apps Bar](http://www.appsbar.com/?gclid=CLXW1dbe5r0CFQJxvAodNIQA5A)

**Link Here :** [App Makr](http://www.appmakr.com/?gclid=CIDkyuze5r0CFc1YpQodE0UA6Q)

**Google It :** [Google](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ulZPU5r0CsbDrAemg4HQDg#q=make%20android%20app%20online)